# Showing Active Items w/ Yii2 Sidenav

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I'm wondering if https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav is capable of showing a page that is not the 'active item' as active. An example being I have my menu item set at `'active' => ($item == 'site/home')`, but I would like to essentially have `site/home2` show the same menu item as active. Treating it as a child page within the same controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can specify which menu item should be active on any particular URL.

For example:

```
['label' => 'Home', 'icon' => 'home', 'url' => Url::to(['/site/home', 'type'=>$type]), 'active' => ($currentPage == 'page1')],
```

here `'active'` specify the codition on which this menu should be active.

so in your case:

```
'active' => ($item == 'site/home' || $item == 'site/home2')
```